# Purple grid noise on shader editor

Tags: osx

When I open the Shader Editor window, purple and green grid noise appear. Also the color of therendered object becames odd. Do you know what causes?
I'm using Blender 2.91.0 on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6

[image]

Comment: Most likely an issue with the GPU. AMD and Mac are not a good combo for blender.

Comment: O... I see. Thank you very much for your advice!  It’s a bit off my original question, I would be very happy if you could share any recommended software doing CG modeling on Mac. Today is my first time to challenge CG, and I can't buy expensive software yet. Thanks again :)